# Table shifts out of page to the right. How do I shrink it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I have a table with a 5 diagrams inside and the table shifts outside of the page. How do I stop this from happening?
Here is code that reproduces the problem

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
% For figures
\usepackage{graphicx} % more modern
%\usepackage{epsfig} % less modern
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\def\layersep{2.5cm}
\def\layersepp{3cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      VAE\\
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{scope}[xshift=-7.5cm,yshift=-5cm,thick,
          node distance=1.6cm,on grid,>=stealth',
          comp/.style={circle,draw=black}]
          \node [comp]  (input)                       {$x$};
          \node [comp]  (latent)  [right=of input]    {$z$} edge [<-, draw=blue,very thick] (input);
          \node [comp]  (copy)  [right=of latent]    {$\hat{x}$} edge [<-, draw=brown, very thick] (latent);
         \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture}\\\hline
      RNN\\
      \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black, node distance=\layersep,transform shape,rotate=90]  %<-- rotate the NN
          \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
          \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,thick,draw,fill=white,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
          \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron];
          \tikzstyle{hoz}=[rotate=-90];


          % hidden states
          \foreach \x / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
          \node[neuron, hoz] (I-\name) at (0,-\x) {$h_\name$};

          \node[hoz] (I-4) at (0,-4) {$\dots$};

          % connect hidden states
          \begin{scope}[
          node/.style={circle,draw=black},
          every edge/.style={draw=red, very thick}
          ]
          \path (I-1.east) edge (I-2.west);
          \path (I-2.east) edge (I-3.west);
          \path (I-3.east) edge (I-4.west);
          \path (I-4.east) edge (I-t.west);

          % inputs states
          \foreach \x / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
          \node[neuron, hoz] (X-\name) at (-1,-\x) {$x_\name$};

          % connect inputs to hidden states
          \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
          \path (X-\name.north) edge (I-\name.south);
          \end{scope}


      \end{tikzpicture}\\\hline
      DANN\\
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{scope}[xshift=-7.5cm,yshift=-5cm,thick,
          node distance=1.6cm,on grid,>=stealth',
          comp/.style={circle,draw=black}]
          \node [comp]  (input)                       {$x$};
          \node [comp]  (latent)  [right=of input]    {$z$} edge [<-,very thick,draw=blue] (input);
          \node [comp]  (label)  [right=of latent,yshift=-0.8cm]    {$L_y$} edge [<-, very thick] (latent);
          \node [comp]  (domain)  [above=of label]    {$L_D$} edge [<-, very thick] (latent);
         \end{scope}
      \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      VRNN\\
      \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black, node distance=\layersep,transform shape,rotate=90]  %<-- rotate the NN
          \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
          \tikzstyle{recurrence}=[<-,color=green]
          \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,thick,draw,fill=white,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
          \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron];
          \tikzstyle{hoz}=[rotate=-90];


          \begin{scope}[every path/.style={very thick}]

              % hidden states
              \foreach \y / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
              \node[neuron, hoz] (H-\name) at (0,-\y) {$h_\name$};

              \node[hoz] (H-4) at (0,-4) {$\dots$};

              % connect hidden states
              \path[color=red] (H-1.east) edge (H-2.west);
              \path[color=red] (H-2.east) edge (H-3.west);
              \path[color=red] (H-3.east) edge (H-4.west);
              \path[color=red] (H-4.east) edge (H-t.west);

              % inputs states
              \foreach \y / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
              \node[neuron, hoz] (X-\name) at (-\layersep,-\y) {$x_\name$};

              % connect inputs to hidden states
              \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
              \path[color=red] (X-\name.north) edge (H-\name.south);

              % latent states
              \foreach \y / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
              \node[neuron, hoz] (Z-\name) at (\layersep,-\y) {$z_\name$};

              % connect inputs to hidden states
              \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
              \path[color=red] (Z-\name.south) edge (H-\name.north);

              % draw inference connections
              \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
              \path[color=brown] (Z-\name.south) edge [bend left=70] (X-\name.north);

              % draw generation connections
              \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
              \path[color=blue] (X-\name.north) edge [bend left=70] (Z-\name.south);
          \end{scope}

      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
    &
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      VADA\\
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black, node distance=\layersep,transform shape,rotate=90]  %<-- rotate the NN
        \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
        \tikzstyle{recurrence}=[<-,color=green]
        \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,thick,draw,fill=white,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron];
        \tikzstyle{hoz}=[rotate=-90];


        \begin{scope}[every path/.style={very thick}]

            % hidden states
            \foreach \x / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
            \node[neuron, hoz] (H-\name) at (0,-\x) {$h_\name$};

            \node[hoz] (H-4) at (0,-4) {$\dots$};

            % connect hidden states
            \path[color=red] (H-1.east) edge (H-2.west);
            \path[color=red] (H-2.east) edge (H-3.west);
            \path[color=red] (H-3.east) edge (H-4.west);
            \path[color=red] (H-4.east) edge (H-t.west);

            % inputs states
            \foreach \x / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
            \node[neuron, hoz] (X-\name) at (-\layersep,-\x) {$x_\name$};

            % connect inputs to hidden states
            \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
            \path[color=red] (X-\name.north) edge (H-\name.south);

            % latent states
            \foreach \x / \name in {0/1, 1.5/2, 3/3, 5/t}
            \node[neuron, hoz] (Z-\name) at (\layersep,-\x) {$z_\name$};

            % connect inputs to hidden states
            \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
            \path[color=red] (Z-\name.south) edge (H-\name.north);

            % draw inference connections
            \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
            \path[color=brown] (Z-\name.south) edge [bend left=70] (X-\name.north);

            % draw generation connections
            \foreach \name in {1,2,3,t}
            \path[color=blue] (X-\name.north) edge [bend left=70] (Z-\name.south);


            % draw label classifiers
            \foreach \x / \name in {-.5/1, 1/2, 2.5/3, 4.5/t}
            \node[neuron, hoz] (X-\name) at (\layersepp,-\x) {$L_y^\name$};

            % draw domain classifiers
            \foreach \x / \name in {.5/1, 2/2, 3.5/3, 5.5/t}
            \node[neuron, hoz] (X-\name) at (\layersepp,-\x) {$L_D^\name$};
        \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
   \\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, can you please explain better what you want? Shrinking can make the graphs unreadable.  How about presenting the diagrams one above the other?

Comment: The package tabu might be worth looking at for you, as it allows you to specify the size of a table explicitly. I could not get it to work immediately with your example though and frankly am not very motivated to get it working. Your table layout is somewhat complex and convoluted in the source. You're probably trying to squeeze too much information in too small a (horizontal) space. So unless you have incredibly tight space constraints I would concur with Kurt and suggest rearenging the graphs for the benefit of both you and the reader.